# How to access codebehind variable in aspx page to set Enabled property

Tags: variables, code-behind

I have a button in aspx page, I want to set its Enabled property using code behind variable.
I did it like this:

'>

It gives me error message:  Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%=this.AllowDelete %>' for the 'Enabled' property.

I changed it to Enabled = <%=this.AllowDelete %>, 
It gives me error message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

I tested <%=this.AllowDelete %> in other place of page, it shows 'false' correctly.

How to set it for enabled property correctly?

It's such a simple question but stuck me for a while. Any help is appreciated. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but are you able to set the button's enabled property in Page_Load function in your code-behind?

```
Page_Load(...)
{
    if(this.AllowDelete)
        btn.Enabled = true;
...
```

Comment: Should be able to do it. Thank you!

Comment: I find it is a little trouble to set it in page_load, because the button is in ItemTemplate of a GridView control. So I can only set it in GridView_databinding event. I will try it to see whether it solve the problem.

Comment: Ah...you should have put that in your question. That could be why you were getting the error in the first place. Yeah, you will need a different implementation to achieve that.

Comment: It is solved by doing it in RowDataBound method. Thanks a lot!